# Modify dataset via Datagridview.SelectedRows in VB .net

Tags: .net, datagridview, datarow

I have a datagridview in which I can select rows. The data displayed in this datagridview is bound via a BindingSource to a datatable in dataset (which I can edit in MS Access).

What I would like to do is **modify values of cells in the Datagridview.SelectedRows, and save those changes to the original dataset**.

On the web I've found multiple cases of the same problem, mostly on C#. For example:
Convert each DatGridviewRow to a DataRowView, and then use DataBoundItem.

But the DataRowView does not have a DataBoundItem property...

If only one row was selected in the datagridview, I could use the BindingSource.Current property, but I have multiple rows in the datagridview selected.

[DataBoundItem not selectable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixurj.jpg)

Comment: The `DataGridView` has a `SelectedRows` property… [DataGridView.SelectedRows Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows?view=netframework-4.8) … Each `DataGridViewRow` in that collection has the [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRow_DataBoundItem) …. Please note the “Remarks” sections on each.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
I tried that, but the problem is that the DataBoundItem property doesn't show up when I declare a DataGridViewRow...

Comment: I added a screenshot in my original post

Comment: I had to test this; and it appears the VB flavor in Visual Studio “intelisense” is missing this property. However, my test showed it should still work. Ignore the intelisense and finish typing … `dgvrow.DataBoundItem` … it should NOT be flagged as an error unless you are using an older version of .NET.